# Can I 'transfer' an iOS app name?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

There is an app in the iOS App Store that's using the name I really want to have. It has 0 reviews, and looks like it hasn't been updated since 2013.

I'm wondering a few questions here about my options...

1. Can I have the official name of my app be one thing (like when you're searching for it), but have the bundle identifier text that shows up under the actual icon be something else (the name which is reserved). I'm mainly concerned about the actual text under the icon.
2. If I were to reach out to this company and they agreed to change the name of their app, is there anything else that would need to happen? Or could they upload a new binary with a new name, and literally 1 second later I click 'create new app' from within the iTunes connect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It mainly depends how different the names are. Lots of apps are named something like "AppName - Best App Ever" in the App Store, but are just called "AppName" on the homescreen. Some app names on the home screen are sometimes acronyms of their App Store names. If the names are completely different, Apple will not allow it.
2. I believe the other company will have to reach out to Apple for switching the name over to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help on #2, regarding question #1, to clarify what I'm asking... what is the actual name which has to be unique? Is it the name which appears in the app store, or is it the name which appears in the phone itself under the icon, or... both?

Comment: For 2 I believe if the other company changed their App Store name you then will be able to use it. Requires synchronisation though :)

Answer (score 0):

As my experience with several projects published on App Store, I can tell you:

1. Your app bundle name (name below icon in your device) is different from your App Store name (App Store name has to be unique).
2. To change your App Store name, you must create a new version and rename with Itunes Connect, then upload a new binary.

   > To make changes to the app information, create a new app version.
3. To change your App Bundle name, you must create a new version, upload new binary with new Bundle name (you can config in info.plist).

Hope you can solve your problem.